# Switch Text Paragraphs in OpenOfficeOrg Writer mailmerge

Tags: openoffice, mail-merge, openoffice-writer

I am using mailmerge to write the same letter with minor differenes to many peolpe. I experienced that switching text paragraphs depending on database values was not easy for me. I ended up putting huge text paragraphs into the database becaus switching did not really work for me.

Actually I dont' understand how writer does it and maybe the boolean evaluation is buggy?

There is some possibility making paragraphs invisible depending on database fields, but it was frustrating. After marking a paragraph as invisible (depending on a condition) it went invisible in the main document and did not come back, I lost the content.

An example in pseudocode of what I want in my mailmerge document:

> {if [[balance]] > 10} We owe you money.
>   Please can you send your bank details.
>   {end if}
>
> {if [[balance]] < -10} Please transfer
>   the remaining amount to our banc
>   account 123... {end if}

Maybe this could be done with makros? But how to combine makros with mailmerge?

Can you tell me what are the pitfalls and how to master them?

I once did this with ms word, it was a lot easier. The normal mailmerge (including database fields in the letters) works fine for me in OpenOffice writer.

Answer (score 0):

Glen: I'm from Zoho. Since your other question about Zoho Show is closed, thought I'll reply here.

Version control is indeed there in Zoho Show. On the right panel, click on the clock icon at the top. You'll see all the versions and you can view and revert back to an older version if you want. Hope this answers your query. Let me know if you have further queries.